# Laravel 8 in subfolder on server having issue in loading css and js

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I have installed my Laravel application on the server inside a folder named admin
However, I am experiencing a problem with css and js files not loading on the correct path
They are loading with root domain instead of example.com/admin

I have done the following:
I tried to rewrite htaccess but it didn't work
I tried overriding the asset function and found that it returned the correct path

My comment above indicates that I'm having an htaccess issue, something redirecting the asset to the root url

This is my htaccess at in subfolder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    Options +FollowSymLinks
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

and this is in public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: "My comment above indicates that I'm having an htaccess issue" - It does? This more likely suggests an incorrect URL-path in your HTML source. (?) Presumably the `/public` directory is inside the `/admin` directory? What are your URLs? Presumably `/admin` is in the URL, but `/public` is not? Why do you have two seemingly complete `.htaccess` files - doing a similar thing? Why do you seem to have two front-controllers? `/admin/index.php` and `/admin/server.php`?

Comment: Thank you for your response, Mr. White 
Since I'm not an expert with htaccess, I'm using the default htaccess of Laravel, which points to the index.php file inside the public folder by the server.php file. 

and my path is very simple www.example.com/admin/

Comment: where admin is my laravel installation which work well only the asset path is not working 

my asset is set like this 
{{ asset('assets/style.css') }}

Comment: "my asset is set like this {{ asset('assets/style.css') }}" - What is the resulting URL-path in the HTML source?

Comment: its example.com while when i check the helper function in core files and i dd it it shows right path example.com/admin/

Comment: "its example.com" - that would seem to be the problem. But that isn't something you fix in `.htaccess`. (`.htaccess` isn't changing the HTML, if that's what you're thinking. (?))

Comment: I think you are right to let me review my code on the helper I will try to track it down when it change and thank you so much for your response